# How does StackCrawlMark work and what is an ESP point?

Tags: c#, multithreading, stack-trace

My question is about the internal [System.Threading.StackCrawlMark](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs,a2e26196860d1ab2,references) enum type. I understand how the enum is used, just not how it works.

According to the reference source:

> declaring a local var of this enum type and passing it by ref into a function that needs to do a stack crawl will both prevent inlining of the calle and pass an ESP point to stack crawl to

Looking at how the enum is used in various classes, I can see it is sometimes passed through up to 4 more methods. (Eg. see usage in [MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/methodbase.cs,11305a9ceab0d732,references) method.)

My question is this: What is an ESP point, and how does passing the StackCrawlMark as a `ref` reference retain the location at which it was created? Once the code eventually reaches the `extern` call, how does it know which method the StackCrawlMark was created in?

Comment: The stack holds both return addresses of methods, instances of value types (if they're not used in anything exciting like closures) and parameters, the combination of which is called a stack frame; ESP is the register holding the stack pointer. The address of a local thus serves as a marker on the call stack that allows you to read back the originating function. To managed code this is essentially magic; the JIT takes care of ensuring such references can be meaningfully used. [This site](https://mattwarren.org/2019/01/21/Stackwalking-in-the-.NET-Runtime/) actually has some nice explanations.

Comment: ESP is the stack pointer register on x86. It probably means the stack pointer.